# I hear a voice each time I am in application

Tags: system, sound, bugs

I am using Elementary OS Hera 5.1 and I have a particular problem.When I turn on my PC today I started to hear a voice that read the content of every software that I use.For example,if I go to the File Explorer a voice suddenly start and read the name of my files,and when I change a directory the same thing happens again.Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me you have enabled the screen reader. To disable it, go to `System Settings` -> `Universal Access` -> `Audio` and turn it off by clicking the slider.

Or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>